# gl_PointCoord in OSX 10.7 Lion

Tags: osx-lion, webgl, three.js

I've come against a really bizarre shader error in many of the particle examples for Three.js. In the latest Chrome and Firefox in OSX 10.7, gl_PointCoord returns (1,0) for every single fragment. This is found in a few of the included examples as well. Specifically, the [Particle Billboards](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_particles_billboards.html) example, the [Particle Billboard colors](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_particles_billboards_colors.html) example, and the [Particle Sprites](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_particles_sprites.html) examples do not work. They render nothing to the screen. However, the [Custom Attributes](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_particles.html) example works fine, despite having almost the exact same code.

I found this bug while running compatibility checks on my own software. I wrote a shader which renders text sprites using particles. This works fine in 10.6, Windows, and Linux. However, 10.7 renders nothing. Further debugging by setting gl_FragCOlor = vec4(gl_PointCoord, 0., 1.); revealed that all the particles get rendered as solid red squares, instead of the expected red-green gradient.

I've been trying to determine what exactly is the difference between the examples that make Custom Attributes work, but not Particle Billboards, but I haven't made very much headway yet. This is exacerbated by the lack of a testing platform, aside from borrowing friends' laptops. Is this a known OS bug?

Comment: after updating to macos 10.7 (lion) my point sprites are also missing. the same code works on windows. It's native opengl compatibility (i.e. no 3.2 core)